# Windows Server 2008 does not like my exe (KernelBase.dll)

Tags: 64-bit, crash, windows-server-2008

I have written an app to run on 64bit Windows Server 2008, it needs to go in the schedular as it needs to run every 15 minutes. For some reason the program crashes after being open for a few minutes (this is without it being in the schedular). The program runs fine on both my 32bit laptop and a colleagues 64 bit laptop, but fails on this server. Error details: 
EventType = APPCRASH
Fault Module Name = KERNELBASE.dll
Fault module Version = 6.1.7600.16385
Exception Code = e053534f
Any help on this would be most appreciated, ive already tried changing the target platform to x64, setting DetectNewerInstalledVersions to false, running as administrator and changing the compatability settings to what the compatability checker recommends (Windows XP Service Pack 2) and still no avail....

Comment: Well i have such strange questions that I dont always get an answer, if I accept an answer that doesnt solve the problem just for the sake of it I am only going to misinform others who read the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's very little to go by.  However, the exception code is EXCEPTION_SOFTSO, a "soft stack overflow" exception.  It is raised when the CLR is about to run managed code but detects that there isn't enough stack space left to safely execute the code.

You'll need a debugger to get to the bottom of it.  Use the Debug + Exceptions dialog to make the debugger stop at the exact point where the exception is raised.

Comment: Its all ive got im afraid, thanks ill give that a go and report back.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I went through with the debugger and it turns out there was nothing wrong with the code, the server was rejecting emails for some reason. We have changed our server so it now works.